# I found 4 very similar wallet addresses. How is this possible?

Tags: addresses, etherscan

These are the addresses:

[0x7cB57B5A97Eabe94205c07890BE3C1aD31E486A8](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7cB57B5A97Eabe94205c07890BE3C1aD31E486A8)
[0x7Cb57B5a97EaBe94205c07890bE4C1aD31E456a8](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7Cb57B5a97EaBe94205c07890bE4C1aD31E456a8)
[0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8)
[0x7CB57b5A97eabe94205C07890beaC1aD31E486a8](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7CB57b5A97eabe94205C07890beaC1aD31E486a8)

They all have transactions on Etherscan, is there a method i don't know to create similar addresses?

Answer (score 7):

Only one of these addresses has outgoing transactions: [0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8), all the rest has only incoming ones.  So only one addresses is definitely owned by somebody, and all the rest are most probably dead addresses, i.e. addresses no one knows private keys for.

You may send ether to arbitrary address, such as [0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789), you don't need to "generate" it.  Just write `0x` and then 40 arbitrary hexadecimal digits.

BTW, the address that has outgoing transactions is labelled as `Mew_Donate_Old`, so it is probably old donation address for MyEtherWallet, and similar addresses are just mistyped donation address, where some people tried to send their donations.

Answer (score 2):

The above addresses are similar, but it means anyway that such addresses are different, regardless if there is a big or a small difference. Very probably the corresponding private keys are completely different each other, and this happens thanks to the cryptography algorithms behind.

On the other side you can verify on Etherscan that switching arbitrarily between capital letters and small letters does not affect the target address, which remains the same (excluding the "x" character close to the 0 in the left side, which is always a small letter).

As you may notice, all the ethereum addresses are obtained combining numbers from "0" to "9" and letters from "A" to "F", so it is possible to change even a single letter or number in the address string to obtain a different (valid) address. In the most cases you will find valid and empty addresses, with no transactions.

A lot harder is, in terms of numerical probability, to randomly find two private keys which bring to two similar addresses.

Hope this helps.